# border-radius is only rounding one corner

Tags: html, css, image, rounded-corners, border-radius

the border-radius css command doesn't seem to be working on all corners.
html:

```
<img style="object-position: -200px -100px;" 
    id="wlimage"
    <!--this is the image giving me problems--> src="https://www.worldatlas.com/r/w1200/upload/56/a1/a7/shutterstock- 
424782349.jpg">
```

css

```
#wlimage {
border-radius: 30px;
width: 50%;
height: 50%;
}
```

Comment: Your HTML code is invalid, there are lots of closing tags missing

Comment: Concerning the border-radius problem, that's due to your `object-position: -200px -100px;` setting, which hides a major part of the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your `object-position` style shifts the image within the `img` frame. The frame is rounded, but you're seeing the (square) edge of the picture itself.

I've added a red border so you can see where the boundary of the `<img>` element is vs. where the edge of the picture is placed within it.

```css
#wlimage {
  border-radius: 30px;
  border: 4px solid red; 
}
```

```html
<img style="object-position: -200px -100px;" 
  id="wlimage"
  src="https://www.worldatlas.com/r/w1200/upload/56/a1/a7/shutterstock-424782349.jpg">
```